# Fatal: Failed to write genesis block: database contains incompatible genesis (have d4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0, new d1a12dd8ee31c1b49425a

Tags: blockchain, go-ethereum

while trying to create a private blockchain, I'm at the stage of connecting geth with genesis file .json. But after running the command:

```
geth init <path to genesis file>
```

here is what I got

> Fatal: Failed to write genesis block: database contains incompatible genesis (have d4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3, new d1a12dd8ee31c1b49425acee37da3070510d0121922250908ce381ac8a4c8725)

and this is what I have in the genesis file:

```
{
    "config":{
        "chainId":4112022,
        "homesteadBlock":0,
        "eip150Block":0,
        "eip155Block":0,
        "eip158Block":0
    },
    "difficulty":"0x400",
    "gasLimit":"0x8000000",
    "alloc":{}
}
```

I've been following [this material](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-your-own-private-ethereum-network/) and others.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a genesis block in the directory you want to write to. Make sure the data directory is empty (except for the keystore) and try again.